# Simple Image Recognition Task in Android: Dominoes Reading

Tags: java, android, computer-vision, image-recognition

I am newbie to the CV field and I am on a relatively simple task, I want to analyse dominoes rock values.

I used blob analysis method, which wasn't really efficient on android for that I used a pure java code which tends to be slower than native C. And background data caused me problems as it could have blobs too.

After too much reading I ran through 'template matching' method which sounds like the best to me, for its low resources need and rotation/scaling tolerance, I can easily save the template of every piece of the dominoes and then match it in the coming image for analysis and counting.

Now all I want is your guidance to libraries/methods that can help me implementing template matching, I prefer pure java but can use native C libs if no choice is found.

P.S: If you find me wrong regarding algorithm I chose, please provide me with your advice.

Answer (score 8):

Image recognition is a high level processing in computer vision first of all you must do some preprocessing and detect the object first.

To do template matching first of all you must find the region of interest of the image you want to recognize. To do that you can choose one from many algorithm like feature based detection and appearance based detection. After finding the ROI (Region of Interest) you can do the template matching (I assume you already understand the concept of template matching)

the summary of it you can see it in the flow diagram below

[image: Template Matching Flow Diagram]

and the example of template matching

[image]

after you understand the whole process you can use some avaible library that supports android platform like [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/platforms/android.html) (Open Source) or [FastCV](https://developer.qualcomm.com/mobile-development/mobile-technologies/computer-vision-fastcv) by Qualcomm both of them use native C so you must use android NDK to compile it.

If you have any question feel free to ask me in the comment :)